# How to get all values including null in a SQL Server case statement?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a big stored procedure, and basically I want to select all values (including null) if my variable `@DimBrowserId` is set to 0. I am using a case statement, however this is only catching values that actually have something and ignoring the NULL valued fields. Because I am using the = clause in the WHERE I cannot do IS NULL. I do not want to have to write 2 IF statements because the stored procedure would then be enormous, so I want to know how to get null values as well. Here is my code:

```
SELECT  
    DATEPART(yy, DATEADD(mi, @Mdelta, d.DimDateValue)),
    DisableCount = COUNT(*)
FROM    
    dbo.FactDisable AS f
JOIN 
    dbo.DimDate AS d ON f.DimDateId = d.DimDateId
JOIN 
    dbo.DimDevice AS v ON f.DimDeviceId = v.DimDeviceId
WHERE   
    d.DimDateValue >= @StartDateGMT 
    AND d.DimDateValue <= @EndDateGMT
    AND f.IsTest = @IncludeTest 
    AND f.DimProductId = @DimProductId
    AND v.DimBrowserId = CASE 
                           WHEN @DimBrowserId = 0 THEN v.DimBrowserId 
                           ELSE @DimBrowserId 
                         END
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(yy, DATEADD(mi, @Mdelta, d.DimDateValue))
```

The code is near the CASE clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change that line to be

`AND (@DimBrowserID = 0 OR @DimBrowserID = v.DimBrowserId)`

If `@DimBroserID` is 0 then no filtering will be applied for this line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(yy,DATEADD(mi,@Mdelta,d.DimDateValue)),
        DisableCount=COUNT(*)
FROM    dbo.FactDisable AS f
        JOIN dbo.DimDate AS d ON f.DimDateId = d.DimDateId
        JOIN dbo.DimDevice AS v ON f.DimDeviceId = v.DimDeviceId
WHERE   d.DimDateValue >= @StartDateGMT AND d.DimDateValue <= @EndDateGMT
        AND f.IsTest = @IncludeTest AND f.DimProductId = @DimProductId
        AND v.DimBrowserId = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@DimBrowserId,0) = 0 THEN v.DimBrowserId ELSE @DimBrowserId END
GROUP   BY  DATEPART(yy,DATEADD(mi,@Mdelta,d.DimDateValue))
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the data stored value is NULL, not the @DimBrowserId variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(@MightBeNull, 0) = 0 THEN ZeroResult ...
```

will be treated as zero if @MightBeNull is null, and whatever @MightBeNull is if it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming null means any browser, a better data model for this scenario might be to set an ID that identifies any browser, instead of setting it to null.

You probably know what you are running into is NULL does not equal NULL in a comparison.

Assuming you don't have control of the data model to fix that, one option would be to coalesce your NULL values to an unused id.

The resulting WHERE clause would look like this, assuming -1 is the unused value you choose.

```
 AND COALESCE(v.DimBrowserId, -1) = CASE WHEN @DimBrowserId = 0 THEN COALESCE(v.DimBrowserId, -1) ELSE @DimBrowserId END
```